# Handle ‘struct <anonymous>’

Tags: c, anonymous-types

All,

I'm trying to understand the usage of the following:

```
struct out
{
  char msg<>;
};
```

If I try (intentionally):

```
struct out result;
result.msg=1;
```

I got the following:

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct <anonymous>’ from type ‘int’
```

I searched struct anonymous but all queries talk about something related to "Union". I'm really lost, appreciate if someone can clarify me the concept.

Thank you!

PS. I need it to return some message from an RPC Stateless Server.

Comment: That struct isn't legit C..unless i'm missing something. It doesn't look like valid c++, either.

Comment: Are you trying to setup a [**flexible array member**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643406/whats-the-need-of-array-with-zero-elements/14643530#14643530) ? If so, you're going to want a length member preceding that (and if you don't, you likely haven't thought this through). If you're not after a flexible member, I have no idea what you're doing.