# How do I return a 2D array inside a function to main in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, return

I read a text file and store the contents in a 2D array called H inside a function, I need to return this 2D array to main somehow so I can use it there and pass it to other functions. I'm not sure how to get the return to work, maybe using pointers. I made the readTxtFile function into a void function to test if the file reading was working (it does) but I can't do anything with the 2D array outside the function. I have two functions getRows() and getCols() that I didn't show here, I can if needed though.

Heres my code so far:

```
int main(void){

    //  int *H;
    //  H = readTxtFile("H.txt");
    readTxtFile("H.txt");
    return 0;
}

void readTxtFile(char *filename){
    int rows, cols;
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!fp){
        perror("can't open H.txt\n");
        //return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    rows = getRows(fp);
    cols = getCols(fp);
    int (*H)[cols] = malloc(sizeof(int[rows][cols]));
    if(!H){
        perror("fail malloc\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for(int r = 0; r < rows; ++r){
        for(int c = 0; c < cols; ++c){
            if(EOF==fscanf(fp, "%d", &H[r][c])){
                fprintf(stderr, "The data is insufficient.\n");
                free(H);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);

    // printH(rows,cols,H);
    //  return H;


}
```

This is what the text file looks like:

```
1 1 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 1 1 0 1
2 2 2 2 2 2
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is defining a structure for the 2D array in term of its:

- number of columns
- number of rows
- pointer to array data in memory

Note that I would *"linearize"* the array, i.e. allocate a single block of memory of size `Columns * Rows * sizeof(int)`, and given the *i* and *j* row and column index, these two indexes can be converted with simple math to a *single* index in the 1D array (e.g. `index = rowIndex * Columns + columnIndex`)

Then, I would just return a pointer to this structure from your ReadTxtFile function:

```
struct IntArray2D {
    int Rows;
    int Columns;
    int* Elements;
};

/* 
 * Define a couple of helper functions to allocate 
 * and free the IntArray2D structure. 
 */
struct IntArray2D* IntArray2D_Create(int rows, int columns);
void IntArray2D_Free(struct IntArray2D* array);

/* 
 * On success, returns a 2D array with data read from file.
 * On failure, returns NULL.
 * NOTE: callers must call IntArray2D_Free() when done 
 */
struct IntArray2D* ReadTxtFile(const char* filename);
```

**EDIT** As an alternative, you could define the array structure has having a header block with rows and columns count, *immediately* followed by the "linearized" 2D array elements, using a *["flexible array member"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643406/whats-the-need-of-array-with-zero-elements)*:

```
struct IntArray2D {
    int Rows;
    int Columns;
    int Elements[];
};
```

You can then define some convenient functions to operate on this custom array structure, e.g.:

```
struct IntArray2D* IntArray2D_Create(int rows, int columns)
{
    /* Check rows and columns parameters are > 0 */
    /* ... */

    struct IntArray2D *p = malloc(sizeof(struct IntArray2D)
                                  + rows * columns * sizeof(int));
    if (p == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    p->Rows = rows;
    p->Columns = columns;

    /* May zero out the array elements or not... */
    memset(p->Elements, 0, rows * columns * sizeof(int));

    return p; 
}

void IntArray2D_Free(struct IntArray2D* array)
{
    free(array);
}

int IntArray2D_GetElement(struct IntArray2D* array, 
                                 int row, int column)
{
    /* Check array is not NULL; check row and column 
       indexes are in valid ranges ... */

    int index = row * (array->Columns) + column;
    return array->Elements[index];
}

void IntArray2D_SetElement(struct IntArray2D* array, 
                                  int row, int column,
                                  int value)
{
    /* Check array is not NULL; check row and column 
       indexes are in valid ranges ... */

    int index = row * (array->Columns) + column;
    array->Elements[index] = value;
}
```

---

Inside your `ReadTxtFile` function, instead of calling `malloc`, you can call `IntArray2D_Create`:

```
struct IntArray2D* ReadTxtFile(const char* filename) 
{ 
    struct IntArray2D* data = NULL;

    /* ... */

    rows = getRows(fp);
    cols = getCols(fp);
    data = IntArray2D_Create(rows, cols);
    if (data == NULL) {
        /* Handle error ... */ 
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Fill the array ... */
```

In particular, instead your:

> ```
> if(EOF==fscanf(fp, "%d", &H[r][c])){
> ```

you can do:

```
    /* int valueReadFromFile */
    if (EOF == fscanf(fp, "%d", &valueReadFromFile)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "The data is insufficient.\n");
    }      
    IntArray2D_SetElement(data, r, c, valueReadFromFile);
```

And then at the end of the function, you can just have:

```
    return data;
}
```

Comment: This looks like it might work. How would I go about defining the IntArray2D_Create() and IntArray2D_Free() helper functions? Are they just like regular functions?

Comment: @user3716193: Yes, they are just _ordinary_ functions. You can call `malloc` and `free` inside them to dynamically allocate the array's memory.

Comment: Im pretty new to programming in C and confused about using struct. Do I need to define an IntArray2D variable inside my main function and then again inside my readTxtFile function and have H returned to main?

Comment: I added some sample code for the array create and free functions.

Comment: Thanks Mr.C64. I still have some confusion regarding how the struct is used in main and inside my readTxtFile function. Do I define an IntArray2D just once inside main and then pass it to my readTxtFile function?

Comment: @user3716193: I added some sample code for ReadTxtFile.

Comment: Everything seems to be working except for for the IntArray2D_SetElement function. I get this error:
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_IntArray2D_SetElement", referenced from:
      _ReadTxtFile in sim-50782f.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [sim] Error 1

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_IntArray2D_SetElement", referenced from:
      _ReadTxtFile in sim-c7beeb.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [sim] Error 1

Comment: @user3716193: Try to remove the inline.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return arrays from functions; return a pointer to an array instead.

Of course, you could create an array (or a pointer to an array) outside of any function (that is, 'global'), and access it from any other function in the same module (or even the same program by using the `extern` keyword), but I don't recommend this to you. It's best to follow the first aproach.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to return the number of rows and columns back to the caller along with the pointer to the array itself (I haven't tried compiling this...):

```
int main(void){

    //  int *H;
    //  H = readTxtFile("H.txt");
    int rows;
    int cols;
    void *array;
    readTxtFile("H.txt",&rows,&cols,&array);

    int (*H)[*cols] = array;

    /* process array here */

    free(array);

    return 0;
}

void readTxtFile(char *filename, int *rows, int *cols, void **array ){
    int rows, cols;
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!fp){
        perror("can't open H.txt\n");
        //return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    *rows = getRows(fp);
    *cols = getCols(fp);
    int (*H)[cols] = malloc(sizeof(int[*rows][*cols]));
    if(!H){
        perror("fail malloc\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for(int r = 0; r < rows; ++r){
        for(int c = 0; c < cols; ++c){
            if(EOF==fscanf(fp, "%d", &H[r][c])){
                fprintf(stderr, "The data is insufficient.\n");
                free(H);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);

    /* cast is not necessary - added to clearly indicate that the
       pointer returned carries no row/column information with it */
    *array = ( void * ) H;
}
```

@Mr.C64's answer essentially does the same, in what I think is a much cleaner fashion.