# Usage of Structures in C

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I am reading the script on the implementation of `malloc` (first-fit), and I am a little confused about the value assignment of metadata structure. Could anyone give some explanations why the `malloc` returns `flag_block->ptr` (as a pointer to the allocated memory)? As far as I can see, there is no specific assignment to it.

```
typedef struct _metadata {
    size_t size;
    char free;
    struct _metadata* next;
    struct _metadata* prev;
    char ptr[];
} metadata;

metadata* flag_block = NULL; 

void *malloc(size_t size)
{
    if (size==0) {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (flag_block == NULL) {
        flag_block = sbrk(size);
        sbrk(sizeof(metadata));
        if (flag_block == (void *)-1) {
            return NULL;
        }
        flag_block->free = 0;
        flag_block->next=NULL;
        flag_block->prev=NULL;
        flag_block->size = size;
        return flag_block->ptr;
    } else {

    /* 
        ....
    */

    }
}
```

Comment: Related: [What's the need of array with zero elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14643406/335858)

Comment: Code has minor bug: return value of `sbrk(sizeof(metadata));` not checked.

Comment: Another subtle weakness to this code: the type of `char ptr[];` is of small consequence aside from its _alignment_.  `malloc()` is expected to return a pointer with an _alignment_ valid in all contexts.  `char ptr[];` does not provide that.  Alternative: Use `max_align_t ptr[]`.

Answer (score 6):

The `ptr` is called a flexible array member; it's an array without a size, and can only appear at the end of a `struct`.

So basically this:

```
return flag_block->ptr;
```

is equivalent to

```
return &flag_block->ptr[0];
```

So it's returning the address of the first byte after the rest of the members in the `struct`.

Comment: Important to note the `sizeof(metadata)`  does not include   the size of the FAM `char ptr[];`, but does include, if any, padding just before `char ptr[];`.